# Acceso con la tecla ENTER

Tags: java

Necesito hacer girar los dados presiondando la tecla Enter, de los cuales la operación esta en otro archivo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

```
public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Printer.print("Press 'enter' to roll the dices");

    }
}
```

Este es el código para girar los dados:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Logic {

    public static void dice() {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int dice1 = (int)(rnd.nextInt(6) + 1);
        int dice2 = (int)(rnd.nextInt(6) + 1);

        Printer.print("Dice 1 = " + dice1);
        Printer.print("Dice 2 = " + dice2);
        int sum = dice1 + dice2;

        Printer.print("Roll: total = " + sum);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes detectar cuando presionan la Tecla `ENTER`, esto se puede hacer por consola mediante [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), comparando con [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) la entrada ingresada por el usuario. si es `vacía`  se interpreta que la tecla presionada fue `ENTER` *(Existen quizá otras formas de validar esto)*

Antes debes `crear` un `Objeto` e `Instanciar` tu `Clase` donde está tu método para Girar los dados. (Tener en cuenta quitar el `static` de tu método `dice`)

```
public void dice() {...}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
  /*Crear e Instanciar la clase de tu métod */
  Logic obj = new Logic();
  /* Entrada del Usuario */
   String enterkey = t.nextLine(); 
   /*Comparación para saber si se presiono Enter*/
  if (enterkey.isEmpty()) {
     /*Si es así , llamas a tu método girarDados */
      obj.dice();  
  }
}
```

Comment: sale un error, la variable t sale que no se puede encontrar el símbolo

Comment: Sí , me falto instanciar la clase `Scanner` , verificar, actualicé mi Respuesta.

Comment: Una pregunta, si tengo método main en esta clase no es necesario crear otra en otro archivo?

Comment: No. No es necesario. Recuerde que la ejecución la hace por archivos. El archivo para que pueda ser ejecutado debe tener un método maín definido.